# How to match all tags containing specific word with regex?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to find all `<divs>` in an html containing the same word, it could be either in the `class=""` or in the `id=""`

Example:

```
<div id="chat_widget_th" class="bg-warning checkbox chat_open_ts">...</div>
<div class="bloom chat_inside_th dark_yellow>...</div>
<div id="opened_widget_chat" class="active show">...</div>
<div class="chat_child modal show fade">...</div>
```

These four `<divs>` are from different pages.

They all correspond to a chat popup that i need to exclude. All of them contain, in some way, the word "chat".

I need to find all the `<divs>` (or other tags) that contain the word "chat" and delete them.
For this I will use the function

```
<script>
var regexclass = /class="\K[^"]*?chat[^"]*?(?=")/;
var regexid = /id="\K[^"]*?chat[^"]*?(?=")/;
$('#regexclass').remove();
$('#regexid').remove();
</script>
```

The above function works correctly when it comes to `id=""`, because it finds everything that is enclosed in the quotes of the id attribute, which is unique.

When it comes to a class, on the other hand, the function does not work, because it returns, as I said, everything that is enclosed in quotation.

I.E

"bloom .chat_inside_th .dark_yellow"

while the function would need to at least eliminate the spaces between the different classe.

".bloom.chat_inside_th.dark_yellow"

Is there any way to eliminate these spaces when searching for classes or, better yet, find exclusively the class that contains the word "chat" like "chat_inside_th"?

Comment: Regex is not going to be a great tool for this issue. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is a better fit and has flexibility for `id` or `class`.

Comment: Both answers worked very well.
Once you discover regex, it feels like a cancer consuming you.
Selector would be the correct answer to my problem.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

`[id*="chat"]` will match all **id** attributes which have *chat* in them

```js
$("#go").on("click",e => { $('[id*="chat"],[class*="chat"]').remove(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chat_widget_th" class="bg-warning checkbox chat_open_ts">one</div>
<div class="bloom chat_inside_th dark_yellow">two</div>
<div id="opened_widget_chat" class="active show">three</div>
<div class="chat_child modal show fade">four</div>

<button id="go">go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regex should not be used to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14251221)

Instead, you can use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to [parse the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString), from which you can select all elements whose `id` or `class` attribute contain `'chat'` and remove them.

```js
const str = `<div id="chat_widget_th" class="bg-warning checkbox chat_open_ts">...</div>
<div class="bloom chat_inside_th dark_yellow>...</div>
<div id="opened_widget_chat" class="active show">...</div>
<div class="chat_child modal show fade">...</div>`;

const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
parsed.body.querySelectorAll('[id*=chat],[class*=chat]').forEach(e => e.remove())

const res = parsed.body.innerHTML;
console.log(res)
```